# Procedural macro parsing weirdness in Rust

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to parse a macro similar to this one:

```
annoying!({
    hello({
        // some stuff
    });
})
```

Trying to do this with a procedural macro definition similar to the following, but I'm getting a behaviour I didn't expect and I'm not sure I'm doing something I'm not supposed to or I found a bug. In the following example, I'm trying to find the line where each block is,
for the first block (the one just inside annoying!) it reports the correct line, but for the inner block, when I try to print them it's always 1, no matter where the code is etc.

```
#![crate_type="dylib"]
#![feature(macro_rules, plugin_registrar)]

extern crate syntax;
extern crate rustc;

use macro_result::MacroResult;
use rustc::plugin::Registry;
use syntax::ext::base::{ExtCtxt, MacResult};
use syntax::ext::quote::rt::ToTokens;
use syntax::codemap::Span;
use syntax::ast;
use syntax::parse::tts_to_parser;

mod macro_result;

#[plugin_registrar]
pub fn plugin_registrar(registry: &mut Registry) {
    registry.register_macro("annoying", macro_annoying);
}

pub fn macro_annoying(cx: &mut ExtCtxt, _: Span, tts: &[ast::TokenTree]) -> Box<MacResult> {
    let mut parser = cx.new_parser_from_tts(tts);

    let lo = cx.codemap().lookup_char_pos(parser.span.lo);
    let hi = cx.codemap().lookup_char_pos(parser.span.hi);

    println!("FIRST LO {}", lo.line); // real line for annoying! all cool
    println!("FIRST HI {}", hi.line); // real line for annoying! all cool

    let block_tokens = parser.parse_block().to_tokens(cx);
    let mut block_parser = tts_to_parser(cx.parse_sess(), block_tokens, cx.cfg());

    block_parser.bump(); // skip {
    block_parser.parse_ident(); // hello
    block_parser.bump(); // skip (

    // block lines
    let lo = cx.codemap().lookup_char_pos(block_parser.span.lo);
    let hi = cx.codemap().lookup_char_pos(block_parser.span.hi);

    println!("INNER LO {}", lo.line); // line 1? wtf?
    println!("INNER HI {}", hi.line); // line 1? wtf?

    MacroResult::new(vec![])
}
```

I think the problem *might* be the fact that I'm creating a second parser to parse the inner block, and that might be making the `Span` types inside it go crazy, but I'm not sure that's the problem or how to keep going from here. The reason I'm creating this second parser is so I can recursively parse what's inside each of the blocks, I might be doing something I'm not supposed to, in which case a better suggestion would be very welcome.

Comment: Do you have some trait imports you are not listing? (I'm thinking specifically of `syntax::ext::quote::rt::ToTokens`.)

Comment: Yeah, I am importing ToTokens, I just didn't post it on this code sample to keep it a bit more simple, the `MacroResult` I'm using here is also out for the same reason. I can post the whole thing if you think it's better?

Comment: Imports of traits that are only used via their methods (i.e. not named, like `MacroResult` is here) are very relevant to the code.

Comment: I added the imports there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is [#15962](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15962) (and [#16472](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16472)), [`to_tokens`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/85fd37f876dad1d4db02208f8a56f02228d975b0/src/libsyntax/ext/quote.rs#L48) has a generally horrible implementation. Specifically, anything non-trivial uses [`ToSource`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/85fd37f876dad1d4db02208f8a56f02228d975b0/src/libsyntax/ext/quote.rs#L95-L98), which just turns the code to a string, and then retokenises that (yes, it's not great at all!).

Until those issues are fixed, you should just handle the original `tts` directly as much as possible. You could approximate the right span using the `.span` of the parsed block (i.e. return value of `parse_block`), which will at least focus the user's attention on the right area.

Comment: That sucks :(. The problem with handling the original tts is that I /really/ need to be able to parse recursively inside the blocks, as the first block is very unlikely to have any useful information in [my case](https://github.com/uorbe001/rustspec). Does someone know of any other options to get a better approximation to the right line?